# How can I create custom image from corda/corda-zulu-5.0-snapshot image?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, corda

I want to create a custom image from `corda/corda-zulu-5.0-snapshot` image so basically I want to put contracts and workflows jars inside /opt/corda/cordapps folder inside container while creating my own image from the corda base image using Dockerfile.
So later I only need to mount volume points except /opt/corda/cordapps.

I have tried these configurations inside my Dockerfile:

```
FROM corda/corda-zulu-5.0-snapshot:latest
USER root
VOLUME ./cordapp-tradefinance-contracts-0.1.jar /opt/corda/cordapps/
VOLUME ./cordapp-tradefinance-workflows-0.1.jar /opt/corda/cordapps/
```

and this also

```
FROM corda/corda-zulu-5.0-snapshot:latest
USER root
COPY ./cordapp-tradefinance-contracts-0.1.jar /opt/corda/cordapps/
COPY ./cordapp-tradefinance-workflows-0.1.jar /opt/corda/cordapps/
```

but any of these Dockerfile is not working.After run the container with new image created when I am checking inside container I am not able to found these jars inside `/opt/corda/cordapps` folder.

```
FROM corda/corda-zulu-5.0-snapshot:latest
USER root
VOLUME ./cordapp-tradefinance-contracts-0.1.jar /opt/corda/cordapps/
VOLUME ./cordapp-tradefinance-workflows-0.1.jar /opt/corda/cordapps/
```

I am expecting that after running the custom-image, these jars should be copied inside /opt/corda/cordapps folder of container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the COPY statement, and not VOLUME (which is used for mounting volumes):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: Thanks Chris Chabot, it worked for me.I was also using volume mount point with copy command so it was overriding the content of that folder.